# Fitting distribution

Tags: probability-distributions

I have the following [distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHL3Z.png) of points and I need to fit a theoretical distribution. It looks like Gamma but I am not entirely sure. Do I have to fit several of them (like Exponential, Poisson etc.) to rule them out or is there a generalized distribution that I can try fitting into that will tell me what is the closest distribution. Something like a generalized normal that can converge on the right type of normal. Generalized normal is clearly ruled out here.

And what would be your best guess for this data. Thanks. Sorry, I couldn't attach an image as don't have required the number of points.

Comment: I would suggest to move this question to [stats.stackexchange.com/](http://stats.stackexchange.com/), however not sure if somebody would want to ask such broad question.

Comment: Do you need it to be a parameterized distribution?

Comment: Yes, preferably. But are there any other options? Thanks!

Comment: negatively skewed probability distribution

Comment: Thanks! Can Gamma be a good approximation?

Comment: Looks more like Extreme Value  Distribution. If you fit with maximum likelihood then you can compare the likelihood of different distributions. (But beware distributions with more parameters will fit better so its not just a case of choosing the most likely.)